# vue.js with vuetify: Can't load google map in mounted

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vuejs2, async-await, vuetify.js

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I'm loading the map script in my App.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-toolbar dark dense app color="primary lighten-1">
      <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">Byte[Gym]</router-link>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
        <v-btn flat>Set</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Workout</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Exercise</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Muscle</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Logs</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Stats</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat to="/about">About</v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>search</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>favorite</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-content>
      <router-view/>
    </v-content>

  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  created(){
      let gmap = document.createElement("script");
      gmap.setAttribute("src", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?");
      document.head.appendChild(gmap);
  },
  data() {
    return {
      //
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

In the Home.vue file:

```
<template>
<v-container>   
     <Gmap></Gmap>
</v-container>
</template>

<script> 
  import Gmap from "@/components/home/Gmap.vue"
  export default {
    components: {  
      Gmap
    }
  }
</script>
```

and finally, in the Gmap.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="map"> 
      <v-btn @click="renderMap">map</v-btn>
      <div v-if="mapReady" class="google-map" id="map"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Gmap",
  data() {
    return {
        mapReady: false,
        lat: 53,
        lng: -2
    };
  },
  methods: {
   async renderMap() {      
      const map = await new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
      {
          center: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng},
          zoom: 6,
          maxZoom: 15,
          minZoom: 3,
          streetViewControl: false
      });

    }
  },  
  async mounted() {
     await this.renderMap();
     this.mapReady = true;
  }
};
</script>
<style>
.google-map {
    width: 505px;
    height: 505px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:transparent;    

}
</style>
```

I have added the Gmap.vue to the called Home.vue
If I click the button, it renders normally. But I would like to have it rendered when loaded.
If I run the code like it is now, I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null"
```

I have tried some of the other npm packeges for vue google map, but not getting them to work.
Everthing works if I remove the mounted hook, and just click the button

If I just use regular(not async) mounted(), I get the following:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: google is not defined"
```

but only the first time I go to "/", , and that is why I have tried the async route.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please could you create jsfiddle to recreate your bug? That way, we can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback guys, but I ended up removing the insertion of the script into the head from the created() hook in the app.vue file, and put the loading of google maps "way up" in the index.html file.

Then everything worked even without async.

I read somewhere that using the created() hook was the perfered way to load the map, but seems not to be the case (at least with the vuetify plugin)

Maybe this has something to do with the fact that vue doesnt register the insertion of the script, and therefor doesn't update the virtual dom..

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's recommended to use:
`this.$el.querySelector()` instead of `document.querySelector()`

You got another mistake in the selector, you use `getElementById` but your `<div>` has a class.

Change the line to:

```
  methods: {
   async renderMap() {      
      const map = await new google.maps.Map(this.$el.querySelector(".map"),
      {
          center: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng},
          zoom: 6,
          maxZoom: 15,
          minZoom: 3,
          streetViewControl: false
      });

    }
  },
```